# Not being able to instantiate templated class with templated method without arguments

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to develop a class that has to be templated and needs to have some templated methods. I have been looking and, most likely because I do not know how to explain my problem, I have not been able to find the solution. Here is my exmaple:

```
template<typename T>
class TestClass{
public:
    template<typename M>
    TestClass(M val): val_(T(val)){}

    template<typename N>
    N func() {
        return N(val_);
    }

    T get() {
        return val_;
    }

    template<typename N>
    N add(N val) {
       return N(val_) + val;
   }

private:
    T val_;
};
```

This class will be called in templated functions such as this one:

```
template<typename T>
std::string str(TestClass<T> f)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << f.func<T>();
    out << "\n";
    out << "get: ";
    out << f.get();
    out << "\n";
    out << f.add<T>(0.0);
   return out.str();
}
```

An here is an example of usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

   TestClass<double> t('a');
    std::cout<<"Manual output: \n";
    std::cout<<"func: "<<t.func<double>()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"get: "<<t.get()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"add: "<<t.add<double>(0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"operator<< output: \n";
    std::cout<<str(t)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled whithout `std::string str(TestClass<T> f)` function and its usage within the `main` and I observe the desired behaberou. However, I cannot compile this code with the following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
    out << f.func<T>();
                   ^ 
expected primary-expression before ')' token
    out << f.func<T>();
                     ^
expected primary-expression before '>' token
    out << f.add<T>(0.0);
                  ^
```

The compiler also produces errors regarding the `<<` operator and the fact that `f.func<T>()` and `f.add<T>` type has not been resolved. If I remove the templated parts in the calls within `str()`:

```
template<typename T>
std::string str(TestClass<T> f)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << f.func();
    out << "\n";
    out << "get: ";
    out << f.get();
    out << "\n";
    out << f.add(0.0);
   return out.str();
}
```

Then, the compiler error is:

```
no matching function for call to 'TestClass<double>::func()'
     out << f.func();
         ^
candidate is:template<class N> N TestClass<T>::func() [with N = N; T = double]
     N func() {
       ^
couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
    out << f.func();
        ^
```

Which make sense because `func()` type can not be deduced. Also I have tryied, using `f.func<T>()` and `f.add(0.0)` but the error is simillar to the first one.

My question is: How should I do it so the compiler can do its job?

Comment: I have already tried that aswell. Sorry for not saying it. Added in my question

Comment: It ran as-is, for me.  What compiler, and command line?

Comment: g++ -o example example.cpp

Comment: I got similar answers with g++.  I was going to suggest -std=c++14 on the command line, but I can't test that, as my ubuntu system isn't up to date. It run on vs2017 (windows).

Comment: Well since T and N are the same type in your sample and func() and get() do the same thing, you can obviously solve your problem by using get() function instead. And for add, you already figure out that it works if you remove <T>. **In any case, it is generally not a good idea to have arbitrary conversion both from and to a class!**

Comment: Your code is way to long to demonstrate the problem... One can make a sample that demontrate the problem calling func() in less than half that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `func` template member function must be labeled as a template function when called:

```
f.template func<T>();
```

The `template` keyword is required to indicate the left angle bracket `<` is **NOT** a less-than operator. See [this explanation of this use of the template keyword](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix).

The `add` member function picks up its template type from the parameter:

```
f.add(0.0); // typename N = double
```

Comment: I might have not explained myself well. I know why `f.add(0.0)` works. My question Is how to get `f.func()` to work sithin the templated function `str()`. The `f.template func<T>()` works perfectly. Why? In the main both templated methods work when called normally.